# Peskin equation 6.38

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, dirac-matrices

In Peskin and Schroeder's QFT book, page 189, equation 6.38, how do they get from the first line to the second line?

In particular, I am stuck on the transition from what I perceive to be:
$$ k'_\alpha \gamma^\alpha m \gamma^\mu + m k_\alpha \gamma^\alpha \gamma^\mu $$
into:
$$ -2m(k+k')^\mu $$

what am I missing?

I thought it might be using the Dirac equation because it works on $u(p)$, but that can't be it since $k\neq p$. Also couldn't figure out how to use the anticommutation relations of the gamma matrices.

Comment: It looks like gamma matrix identities. You're first equation is incomplete. The terms you're trying to simplify has 4 gamma matrices in the textbook, you should use their anticommutation relations and the identity they mention in the line below the equations to simplify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verifying this in its entirety is tedious but good practice, so here's the skeleton of what you need to do without giving it all away:

1. Recall the fundamental structure relation
   \begin{align}
     \{\gamma^\mu, \gamma^\nu\} = 2g^{\mu\nu}
   \end{align}
   where, as usual, there is an identity matrix implicit on the right hand side.
2. The expressions you really want to compare are the expression on the first line which reads
   \begin{align}
     -ig_{\nu\rho}(-ie\gamma^\nu)i(k_\alpha\gamma^\alpha + m)\gamma^u i (k_\beta \gamma^\beta+m)(-ie\gamma^\rho)
   \end{align}
   and the expression on the second line which reads
   \begin{align}
     2ie^2(k_\alpha\gamma^\alpha\gamma^\mu\gamma^\beta k'_\beta -2m(k+k')^\mu+ m^2\gamma^\mu)
   \end{align}
3. It's useful to match the stuff in each line that doesn't depend on $k$ and $k'$ first, and then match the stuff that does depend on $k$ and $k'$.  For example, the term on the first line that doesn't have $k$ and $k'$ in it is
   \begin{align}
     -ie^2g_{\nu\rho}\gamma^\nu\gamma^\mu\gamma^\rho m^2
   \end{align}
   while the stuff on the second line that doesn't have $k$ and $k'$ in it is
   \begin{align}
     2ie^2m^2\gamma^\mu
   \end{align}
   These things are the same since
   \begin{align}
     g_{\nu\rho}\gamma^\nu\gamma^\mu\gamma^\rho
   &= g_{\nu\rho}\gamma^\nu(\{\gamma^\mu, \gamma^\rho\} - \gamma^\rho\gamma^\mu) \\
   &= g_{\nu\rho}\gamma^\nu(2g^{\mu\rho}-\gamma^\rho\gamma^\mu) \\
   &= 2\gamma^\mu-g_{\nu\rho}\gamma^\nu\gamma^\rho\gamma^\mu \\
   &= 2\gamma^\mu-\frac{1}{2}(g_{\nu\rho}\gamma^\nu\gamma^\rho + g_{\rho\nu}\gamma^\rho\gamma^\nu)\gamma^\mu \\
   &= 2\gamma^\mu - \frac{1}{2}g_{\nu\rho}\{\gamma^\nu,\gamma^\rho\}\gamma^\mu \\
   &= 2\gamma^\mu - \frac{1}{2}g_{\nu\rho}(2g^{\nu\rho})\gamma^\mu \\
   &= 2\gamma^\mu-4\gamma^\mu \\
   &= -2\gamma^\mu
   \end{align}
4. Do a similar (but more tedious) thing for the stuff that depends on $k$ and $k'$.

Comment: Thank you! I needed two more identities: $\gamma^\mu \gamma^\nu \gamma^\rho \gamma_\mu = 4\eta^{\nu\rho}$ and $\gamma^\mu \gamma^\nu \gamma^\rho \gamma^\sigma \gamma_\mu = -2\gamma^\sigma \gamma^\rho \gamma^\nu$. However, working on this, another question arose: at least as far as I can tell, the Feynman rules don't exactly stipulate in which order to write down the various terms of the diagram. When I initially wrote down the diagram without looking at what the book had, I had different order. Namely, I had $k$ before $k'$. How do you decide on that? Or it just means complex conjugation?

Comment: @Psycho_pr No Problem.  Yeah those sorts of identities are useful; note also that they can be derived using the fundamental structure relation in 1.  As for the order, recall that an outgoing external electron is assigned $\bar u$ (which is a row vector) while an in-going one is assigned $u$ (which is a column vector), so for the matrix multiplications to make sense (namely to get a scalar in the end), you should start with the outgoing $p'$ and then trace "against" the arrows along the fermion line to obtain the correct order.